# Python function does not run on command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, command-line-interface

I have trouble executing a python in a terminal.

My file name is `ex18.py` and I am using python 3.7.

To run my function I write the following on terminal:

`$ python3.7 ex18.py`

This is how my code looks like:

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print(f"arg1: {arg1}, arg2: {arg2}")

def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
    print(f"arg1: {arg1}, arg2: {arg2}")

def print_one(arg1):
    print(f"arg1: {arg1}")

def print_none():
    print("I got nothing.")

    print_two("Zed", "Shaw")
    print_two_again("Zed","Shaw")
    print_one("First!")
    print_none()
```

I expect to see the following when I run it on terminal:

```
arg1: Zed, arg2: Shaw
arg1: Zed, arg2: Shaw
arg1: First!
I got nothing.
```

Comment: Are the four last lines indented? Should they be moved further left?

Answer (score 3):

The last four lines are indented, so they belong to the same block as line `print("I got nothing.")`, i.e. they are inside `print_none()` function.

Just to remind, indentation in python is a part of syntax, denoting a code block (but an empty line is just an empty line).

To make your code working, just **unindent those lines**.

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can define functions, which are snippets of code once they are called. The last four lines seem to call the functions defined earlier, but they are currently indented, which means it will run as part of the indented block of code (so those lines are part of the `print_none` function).

This means to the computer, you have defined four functions, but have not called any of them. As a result, none of functions are going to be run by the computer. Try the following code to that runs the functions above. Notice the indentation of the last four lines.

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print(f"arg1: {arg1}, arg2: {arg2}")

def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
    print(f"arg1: {arg1}, arg2: {arg2}")

def print_one(arg1):
    print(f"arg1: {arg1}")

def print_none():
    print("I got nothing.")

print_two("Zed", "Shaw")
print_two_again("Zed","Shaw")
print_one("First!")
print_none()
```